# In texture paint mode, is there a way for brush to be normal to surface instead of parallel with viewport?

Tags: texture-painting

By default when you draw a brush stroke in texture paint mode, the paint is applied as if you're spraying paint from the pixel you clicked on in the viewport to the model.  It would be useful if instead the brush was transformed so that it was spraying at the point on the model under your mouse cursor and normal to the surface.

Is there a way to do this?  I can't find anything obvious in the brush settings.

Comment: Well, looks like that didn't happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet, but the ability to do so is coming since Pablo Dobarro has coded it in development and it should be coming in official 2.82 later on. He made it consistent with the way the new 2.81 sculpt brush drawing works with the brush following the normal.